# A Question about Productively Lindelöf Metrizable Spaces

Tags: general-topology

I've been reading more productively Lindelöf spaces and the Michael Space Problem. The Michael Space Problem asks if there exists a Michael Space.

- A topological space $X$ is productively Lindelöf if it's product with any Lindelöf space $Y$ is also Lindelöf.
- A topological space $X$ is a Michael space if it's Lindelöf, but it's product with $\mathbb{P}$ (the set of irrational numbers) is not Lindelöf.

In an [article](http://www.math.toronto.edu/tall/publications/maybeD.pdf) by F.D. Tall, he states:

> The Continuum Hypothesis (CH) implies that productively Lindelöf metrizable spaces are $\sigma$-compact.

He also mentions that this is implicitly proved in E. Michael's [article](http://archive.numdam.org/ARCHIVE/CM/CM_1971__23_2/CM_1971__23_2_199_0/CM_1971__23_2_199_0.pdf), and explicitly stated and proved in an [article](http://zbmath.org/?q=an:0688.54013) by K. Alster, but I am not able to access Alster's article.

Michael's article shows how CH can be used to create a Michael space, that is:

> CH implies there exists a Lindelöf space $X$ such that $X \times \mathbb{P}$ is not Lindelof.

I've read through the proofs in Michael's article, but I'm not sure how it can be implicitly shown that Lindelöf metrizable spaces are $\sigma$-compact if CH is assumed.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: So Tall is saying that Michael implicitly showed that, for *any* non-$\sigma$-compact metric space $P$ (not necessarily the space $\mathbb P$ of irrational numbers), one can use CH to create a Lindelöf space $X$ such that $X\times P$ is not Lindelöf? Have I got that right? What properties of $\mathbb P$ does Michael's construction use? I suppose he uses more than just the mere fact that $\mathbb P$ is a separable metric space which is not $\sigma$-compact?

Comment: Michael's construction uses the fact that $\mathbb{P}$ is dense in the real line, and $\mathbb{P}$ is not an $F_\sigma$-set in the real line. A similar proof can be found here: http://dantopology.wordpress.com/2012/10/28/michael-line-basics/ . As long as a partition of the real line, $X$, is: isolated, dense, and not an $F_\sigma$-set in the real line, the same proof can show that the product of the modified Michael line and the space $X$ (with the usualy topology) is not normal.

Comment: What do you mean by "partition" here? And what does "isolated" mean?

Comment: In the construction, Michael took the real line and retopologized the irrationals to be discrete, it became "isolated."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the record, Alster’s paper is available from [this page](http://pldml.icm.edu.pl/pldml/element/bwmeta1.element.desklight-c3b8bb79-9be2-486c-afd5-4a7f6734644b?q=bwmeta1.element.desklight-625bcd63-6c8e-4718-bb1c-16152d00407f;1&qt=CHILDREN-STATELESS). The relevant result (slightly restated) is

> **Proposition** $\mathbf{1}$**:** Assume that the Continuum Hypothesis holds. Then if $Z\subseteq\Bbb I^A$ and $Z$ is productively Lindelöf, then for every countable $S\subseteq A$ the space $p_S[Z]$ is $\sigma$-compact, where $p_S$ denotes the projection from $\Bbb I^A$ onto $\Bbb I^S$.

If $Z$ is metrizable, then $Z$ embeds in $\Bbb I^\omega$, $Z$ itself is $\sigma$-compact.

The proof isn’t too bad. Suppose not, and let $S\subseteq A$ be countable and such that $p_S[Z]$ is not $\sigma$-compact. Let $B=\Bbb I^S\setminus p_S[Z]$; if $B$ were a $G_\delta$ in $\Bbb I^S$, $p_S[Z]$ would be $\sigma$-compact, so $B$ is not a $G_\delta$ in $\Bbb I^S$. By $\mathsf{CH}$ there are $\omega_1$ open sets in $\Bbb I^S$ containing $B$, say $\{U_\xi:\xi<\omega_1\}$. For $\eta<\omega_1$ let $G_\eta=\bigcap_{\xi\le\eta}U_\xi$; then $\langle G_\xi:\xi<\omega_1\rangle$ is a non-increasing $\omega_1$-sequence of $G_\delta$ sets in $\Bbb I^S$ such that if $U$ is any open nbhd of $B$ in $\Bbb I^S$, there is a $\xi<\omega_1$ such that $B\subseteq G_\xi\subseteq U$. Since $B$ is not itself a $G_\delta$ in $\Bbb I^S$, $G_\xi\cap p_S[Z]$ is uncountable for each $\xi<\omega_1$, so for each $\xi<\omega_1$ we can choose a point $x_\xi\in G_\xi\cap p_S[Z]$ in such a way that the points $x_\xi$ are distinct.

Let $X=B\cup\{x_\xi:\xi<\omega_1\}$, and refine the subspace topology that it inherits from $\Bbb I^S$ by making each $x_\xi$ an isolated point; let $\tau$ be the resulting topology. Let $\mathscr{V}\subseteq\tau$ be an open cover of $X$. $\Bbb I^S$ is compact and metrizable, so it’s hereditarily Lindelöf, and there is a countable $\mathscr{V}_0\subseteq\mathscr{V}$ that covers $B$. By construction $X\setminus\bigcup\mathscr{V}_0$ is countable and hence Lindelöf, so $X$ is Lindelöf. However, $\{\langle x_\xi,x_\xi\rangle:\xi<\omega_1\}$ is a closed discrete subset of $X\times p_S[Z]$, which is therefore not Lindelöf, contradicting the fact that productive Lindelöfness is preserved by continuous maps. $\dashv$

I’ve not gone through the details, but this is basically derived from the construction of Michael’s Example $1.2$.